# Finding $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}{n^{3/2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, radicals, riemann-sum

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}{n^{3/2}}$$

How to find the limit? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

By [Stolz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) we have:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}{n^{3/2}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^{3/2}-(n-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}\left(n^{3/2}+(n-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)}{n^3-(n-1)^3}=$$
$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^2+\sqrt{n(n-1)^3}}{3n^2-3n+1}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: Looks like serial down voting.  +1 to compensate

Comment: @Dr. MV In this forum sometimes we get very many up-votes for primitive questions and down-votes for beautiful solutions  or  problems. This is our life here.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg You're right.  I've had such experiences.  ;-)

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:**

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt k}{n^{3/2}}=\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}$$

Now, think about a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Methods).

Alternatively, [bound the sum by integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#Proof) as

$$\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\int_1^{n+1}\sqrt{x}\,dx\le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt k}{n^{3/2}}\le \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\int_1^{n}\sqrt{x}\,dx$$

and use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Why was this down voted??  Would the down voter care to comment?

Comment: The definite route to go for such limits is the Riemann sum. +1

Comment: And downvoters please have some courage to write a comment.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, I agree.  In the original post, the OP had mentioned the use of the squeeze theorem.  So, I added the alternative.  Any way ... thank you as always my friend!