# Evaluating the limit of a sqrt function using Riemann Sums

Tags: calculus, limits, riemann-sum

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt1+\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\ldots+\sqrt n}{n\sqrt n}$

I am having trouble doing this problem. I have attempted to take the Riemann Sum but cannot get past the square root. I also tried to upper-bound and lower-bound it, but I got stuck doing this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1172144/problem-on-limits-lim-n-to-infty-frac-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt4, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114065/limit-lim-n-to-infty-n-3-21-sqrt2-ldots-sqrtn-lim-n-to-infty?noredirect=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2126922/finding-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-frac-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-cdots-sqr?noredirect=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149746/lim-n-to-infty-frac-sqrtn-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrtnn2?noredirect=1